# Transpose applications and matrices properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Good Afternnon

If $f$ is a linear transformation mapping then if the transformation matrix of linear transformation mapping **has been defined** and its transpose properties are known as well.

Why, what I have written below, is called a definition rather than a proposition?? Is it possible to deduce it from the matrices?

> $E,F$ two finite vector-spaces.
>
> $\psi\in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$. The transpose of $\psi$ is the linear map :
>
> $\begin{array}l ^t\psi :&F^*&\to E^*\\&\phi&\to \phi\circ\psi\end{array}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the transpose of a matrix is one thing and the tranpose of a linear map is a distinct concept.